# Decide whether the function $g(\overline{z}) = z$ has a primitive in any open subset of $\mathbb{C}$.

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, complex-numbers

Decide whether the function $g(\overline{z}) = z$ has a primitive in any open subset of $\mathbb{C}$.

Im really not sure how to answer this question so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: if a function has a primitive, it is holomorphic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $h : U \to \mathbb C$ is a primitive for $g$ on the open set $U \subset \mathbb C$, then $h$ is differentiable, by definition.

But derivatives of holomorphic functions are also differentiable. [Indeed, if $f$ is any differentiable function in $U$, then $f$ has a Taylor expansion around every point in $U$. But Taylor expansions can be differentiated infinitely many times within their disk of convergence. Thus if $f$ is differentiable in $U$, it is also twice-differentiable.]

Anyway, if $g = h'$ on $U$, it would follow that $g$ is itself differentiable on $U$.

But $g(z) = \bar z$ is not differentiable anywhere. It does not satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations.